# How to resume release upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I was upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 via ssh (didn't use `screen`). My ssh connection was interrupted when `do-release-upgrade` script was about to remove obsolete packages. Now when I reconnect and run it it just says `No new release found`. How to finish upgrade process?

Comment: `sudo screen -D -r`: http://serverfault.com/a/427008/7113

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Finally run (probably not needed):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. This is the correct answer. My `do-release-upgrade` crashed upgrading 14.04 to 16.04, and re-running it said there was "No new release found" despite most packages still being for 14. Running these commands completed the upgraded successfully. The only caveat is that I had to run `sudo killall dpkg` to kill the stuck dpkg process.

Comment: The screen trick did not work for me after I tried to edit a config file at the shell. Things got hairy. At the end there was no screen to resume, but silly dpkg was still running. In my case, this was still the working solution in 2022 for Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`do-release-upgrade` saves a log file about all the actions taken during the upgrade in `/var/log/dist-upgrade` there are also other logs in `/var/log/apt`, `/var/log/dpkg` which may be relevant.

Comment: Why do I need the logs? Where were no errors, command was just interrupted just at the beginning of step of removing obsolete packages.

Comment: That your SSH connection dies doesn't mean that the process stopped/was killed. If it's not too late you can check `ps ax | grep do-release` and will find the process still running. You can catch it again using something like this http://serverfault.com/a/272526/180142

Comment: just checked - it is not running

Comment: check the logs and see what he did.

Comment: As I already said it stopped after `Start checking for obsolete pkgs` message in log

Comment: Sorry but what log file? `dpkg`, `apt`? Could you edit your question and add the last 10 lines?

Answer (score -3):

Can you check /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and see if it's set to "prompt=never"?

I had an issue where an old server that I inherited wasn't picking up the fact that a new LTS release was available. That was how I fixed it.

Example:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
prompt=lts
```